# Is TLS 1.2 supported for service bus 1.1 in windows server 2008R2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager

we have workflow manager 1.0 and service bus 1.1 installed in SharePoint 2013 on premises server .
SharePoint servers are running with windows servers 2008 R2.

we need to migrate to TLS 1.2

While going through the link [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4077554/add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-on-service-bus-for-windows-server), the Microsoft provided installed update is tested and supported for Windows server 2012 on wards.

Is windows server 2008 R2 supports TLS 1.2 for server bus 1.1?

any one tested?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is supported with the release of CU5 for Workflow Manager 1.0. [Description of the Cumulative Update 5 for Workflow Manager 1.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055730/description-of-the-cumulative-update-5-for-workflow-manager-1-0)

If you read the above article, it is clearly saying under **Features that are added in this update**

- Adds support for the TLS protocol versions 1.1 and 1.2.

You have to meet all prerequisite as they mentioned in the article.

Comment: the provided link in your response is about installing CU5 for workflow manager.  I have to first update the service bus 1.1 with TLS 1.2 before going to install workflow manager CU5 and the microsoft support link is showing the service bus 1.1 with TLS 1.2 support is available from windows server 2012 onwards. can you please clarify whether it supports windows server 2008 R2?

Comment: what my understanding with it, recently i worked on Service Bus related issue. You need Service Bus 1.1. with kb 3086798, then install Windows Azure pack service tls 1.2  and WFM cu 5.0 ( install it from Web platform Installer), yes it worked on windows 2008 r2 as it supported for SharePoint 2013.